# setting textview visibility to GONE when there is no text to show

Tags: android, listview, textview, visibility

i have a listview in which i have 2 textviews, one of these textview contains zero text by default, but can be changed by the user. the problem is that i need to do so when the textview is empty the visibility of it is set to GONE. i have 2 ideas of how this might work, either defining it in xml or defining it in the database somehow.

```
public long createDate(String date) {
    ContentValues initialValues1 = new ContentValues();
    initialValues1.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues1.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, "00:00");

    if(text==""){
       initialValues1.put(KEY_DICTTAG,View.GONE); //this does NOT work
    }else{
       initialValues1.put(KEY_DICTTAG,text);
    }

    initialValues1.put(KEY_DICTALARMTIME, "0");
    initialValues1.put(KEY_DICTLISTIMAGE, R.drawable.list_icon);
    return mdiktationsDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues1);
}
```

i know the textview wont be seen by the user when there is no text, but i need it to not be seen by the system so to speak. this is because i need the timestamp textview to be centerd in the relative layout when there is no text in the dicttag textview. i could not post the xml layout because i do not have any room

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of your code. What is for instance `initialValues1`? A bit more context please :)

Answer (score 3):

It is a little unclear what the actual problem is but here goes....

First, are you sure that your if statement is working properly? You are comparing a String in Java with `==`. I don't know where `text` is but use `if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(""))` instead.

Second, `TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on your TextView should work as intended assuming you are handling it on the main UI thread. You can always override your ListView adapter and make a custom adapter and do your visibility operations there for each item in the ListView. There are plenty of posts and tutorials for doing that.

Comment: how do i go by using TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE) on 1 specific item in my list? without making a custum adapter?

Comment: I have not done anything like that, I always make my custom adapter because it gives me full control in a elegant way.

Comment: @emil writing custom adapters is good for the health of any android developer. No fear!

Comment: ok i will have to try it out! looking for an easy tutorial as we speak, if you knwo of oneplease link to it:) would like to not only now how to do it but also what bennifits it gives me and how to using a custum adapter is different from the stock one :)

Answer (score 1):

txt.setVisibility(View.GONE) for hide 
txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); for show

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (text.equals (""))` instead of `if (text == "")`